# Disabling Pytest capturing with annotation or inline, per test

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, pytest

When I run my tests from the command line I can do,

```
pytest -s <name_of_test>
```

to disable capturing. Is there a way to do this as a test annotation like:

```
@pytest.mark.capture_disabled
def test_foo():
    print('This is a made-up annotation.')
```

Other alternatives are accepted as well, I just want Pytest not to perform capturing for the given test. As a side note,

```
def test_blaa(capsys):
  with capsys.disabled():
      logger.info("Doesn\'t do what I want.")
```

doesn't provide the necessary behaviour.

I am testing some logging and my err and out get consumed. The nasty workaround is to setup the logger at the start of each test and then remove the handler at the end.

```
def test_blaa(capsys, check):
    _, handler = logging.setup("") <-- If these three lines are missing
    root = stdlog.getLogger()
    logger = logging.get_logger()

    logger.info("Some message\n\ton two lines.")

    out, err = capsys.readouterr() <-- err and out are empty
    check.equal(err, "")

    out = out.splitlines()
    check.equal(len(out), 1)
    out = out[0]

    check.is_in("Some message\\n\\ton two lines.", out)
    check.is_not_in("\n", out)

    root.removeHandler(handler)
```

To make it neater I just want to setup the logger once in the setup_module() then at the end use the teardown_module() to remove the handler.

Comment: Are you talking about printing or logging? `with capsys.disabled():` context will disable capturing of `sys.stdout` and emit all `print`s to terminal. Writing an autouse fixture that checks whether the test has the marker and disables `capsys` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I am speaking about logging, the team has developed an extension of the standard Python logging package. Also, when setting up the stream handler it has been redirected to ```sys.stdout```, as follows     ```handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)```. To be honest I think there is another bug with the way logging handlers are setup. https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3819

Comment: Turning off logging capture mechanism is pretty nasty and there's no pendant to `capsys.disabled` in `caplog`. You can move the three lines from the test to an autouse fixture and in it check whether the test has the custom mark; if mark is present, you invoke the logging monkeypatching and revert it on test teardown.